# Minecraft Pushable Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a legend of zelda minecraft custom map, and zelda games have pushable blocks, so I've been busting my head for a long time trying to figure this out, and I couldn’t, so I turned to arqade for help. If you can help me that will be great.

P.S.: I’m in minecraft version 1.12.2

Comment: I don't understand your question. Most blocks are pushable.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use *entities* instead of blocks. Things like mobs (skeleton, pig, cow...), boats, minecarts...

Realistically, I could see you laying minecart tracks that point specific directions (so you can push a "block" around a corner, for instance), then have a pushable block be a minecart.

So you might have tracks like this:

```
-------
|
|
X
```

Where *X* is the minecart, and `|` and `-` are tracks. Then you could push the cart forward or backward until it hits the other track, then you could push it "horizontally" into whatever place you expect.

This also means you can use redstone-track features like pressure plates and powered rails to "listen" for minecarts being moved into locations you want, etc.

Answer (score 0):

@Jishwa66. I think glazed teracotta might be your answer. As you can see from my screenshots below, the piston can push the teracotta and the other one can push the slime block, but they don't push each other.
[image: Piston pushing slime block]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, Jishwa66. When I answered your question earlier, I hadn't understood it properly. This is for if you want a piston pushable block that doesn't stick to slime blocks but every other block is pushable except for obsidian and furnaces. I hope this helped you.

Comment: Thank you so much, user209814, but im looking for an answer with command blocks cause i want it to test for if you are near a block so you can push it in the direction you are facing. but i thank you for taking the time to come up with an answer!

Comment: From the comments you made on my answer, @jishwa66, it looks like (correct me if I’m wrong) you want to be able to have a redstone signal emitted when a player is detected in a certain range, is that right?

Comment: Yes! tha'ts exactly it!

Comment: Ok. @Jishwa66 are you on mcpe (bedrock edition) or mcpc (java edition) and what version.

Comment: im on mcpc 1.12.2

Comment: Hi, @Jishwa66, If you are on MCPC 1.12, you are able to use the /testfor command, however you cannot use it in 1.13.

Comment: /testfor can be rather complicated, so I'll explain it in a more digestible way for you. Say I wanted to test for the nearest player within the range of `Y`. It would be: `/testfor @p[r=Y]`. If I wanted to find out if `personx` is in the range of `Y`, i would do: `/testfor @p[name=personx, r=Y]`.

Comment: Then put a comparator out of the command block followed by a repeater. Make sure to change the command block from `impulse` to `repeat` and to change it from `needs redstone` to `always active`.